# Is it possible to fit a special size for tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I use tkinter in python and I want to fix the size of a window in tkinter for always it means that if user wants to change it by restore button the window size not changed.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("1800x900")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've fully understood your question, but to enforce a fixed window size I've used to set min and max to the same value, as follows.

```py
from Tkinter import Tk
root=Tk()
fixed_geometry=180,90
root.minsize(*fixed_geometry)
root.maxsize(*fixed_geometry)
root.mainloop()
```